# Is it acceptable to bounty old questions that have already been "resolved"?

Tags: discussion, bounties

Is it permissible to bounty a question that is old (say, a year or older) even if it already has an answer? Is the bounty option specifying that a question needs to receive more attention allowed to be used if the question already has a high view count or has an accepted answer, or can bounties only be applied to questions with low view counts or which moderators consider to be currently unresolved?

Comment: You are allowed to dump your own reputation into any Question hole of your choosing.

Comment: @rene Thanks. Can you write an answer? I had a bounty manually canceled and I was wondering if it was just moderators being helpful but misunderstanding the purpose of the bounty, or if the question was too old.

Comment: No thanks, I'd rather stay away from drama between you and moderators ... thanks for notifying me in time, appreciated.

Comment: @rene I don't think there's any drama here, luckily. It seems more like a misunderstanding.

Comment: There is a bounty reason for examplary answers that deserve extra rewarding. That would be a valid case to set one on an old Q that has answers. As I read this has something to do with a dispute between you and a mod, so it might be wise to ask for an explanation on the per site meta.

Comment: @Luuklag Well, this kind of _is_ the per-site meta (it's about MSE). And while someone else also told me that I could award an existing answer, another mod said that I shouldn't, but was unable to elaborate.

Comment: Well that makes it a special case, as I think bounties on here are a bit different then on a main site. Also the question you put it on, I learned from a differt topic, is very specific to one single case, and not written to be really broadly applicable. If the latter was the case I dont see any harm in applying a bounty, but in this case it boils down to actions from a moderator being questioned, appologies were made and the issue was resolved. I dont see any reason why there should be more attention to such negativity. But now there is the streissand effect afterall.

Comment: @Luuklag Indeed. What I _personally_ wanted was for someone to post another answer explaining that this is not acceptable, or an _official_ apology in said mod's answer itself (rather than in chat), since it was a really major overreaction by the mod. There's no way for that to be done without opening a bounty. As I see it, even if it is a specific case, there should be nothing wrong with using my own rep for a bounty.

Comment: "What I personally wanted was for someone to post another answer explaining that this is not acceptable, or an official apology in said mod's answer itself (rather than in chat), since it was a really major overreaction by the mod. " I don't see how you have the right to demand that, seeing you are not a party involved in that dispute. The way for that to be done, if you really feel strongly about that, would be to write your own answer. Which I would advise against, as you are not a concerned party in that dispute.

Comment: @Luuklag I don't have any right to demand that. A bounty is not a demand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why was the bounty on this question cancelled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332843/why-was-the-bounty-on-this-question-cancelled) Seeing that this is the more broadly written version of that question, where it turned out from comments that OP is looking for an answer to that specific case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR

A bounty can be started on a question two days after the question was asked. There is no other limitation as to when a question can be offered a bounty.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)

> Is it permissible to bounty a question that is old (say, a year or older) even if it already has an answer?

Yes.

> Is the bounty option specifying that a question needs to receive more attention allowed to be used if the question already has a high view count or has an accepted answer

Yes.

> can bounties only be applied to questions with low view counts or which moderators consider to be currently unresolved?

No.

Comment: This question is not asking about technical possibility, but about whether it's acceptable and ethical or not.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog that is not asked at all. Only those who know the context make that link. Don't confuse users and visitors with misleading comments on an honest answer of a trick question. That is not nice.

Comment: @rene I got that comment from the use of the word "permissible" rather than "possible" in the question, *not* from any external context.

Answer (score 2):

As [@CinCout's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/332839/295232) shows, it's technically possible. If there would be a good reason to prevent this in general, the developers would have grayed out the Draw Attention option if there were any (positively scoring?) answers.

However, ***in rare cases***<sup>†</sup>, it can be that the ♦ moderators feel that there's no need to open old wounds, whether that is because of an edit to the post, a new answer or a bounty. Some things should definitely not be forgotten, but drawing more attention to it is just ... inappropriate and/or not likely to improve the general atmosphere here. Remember that

> Moderators are human exception handlers, there to deal with those exceptional conditions that could otherwise disrupt the community

([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators))

A similar case would be somebody putting a bounty on a list-like question which should've been closed, historically locked and/or deleted. I can imagine myself removing a bounty from such a question, *especially* if the 'Draw Attention' reason has been chosen.

<sup>†</sup>: I'm not sure if your recently removed bounty applies, I've only skimmed the question and wasn't involved in the incident or the decision to remove the bounty. I would have said the same even if we were talking about a hypothetical situation.

Comment: Reading the other recent question about this particular "incident" I think this is one of those "rare cases" you mention.

Comment: @Luuklag That's what I think too. The question in question was pointing out previous abuses by staff which, while resolved, I believed have answers that can be improved. I can see how staff would not want me to highlight such questions, but I also believe that it should not be their place to prevent that. After all, if a question is so bad that bringing attention to it is against the rules, the question should be locked or deleted.